# how to modify httpd-xampp.conf file

Tags: security, xampp

I've setup xampp on my server then I tried to change security configuration in this file `httpd-xampp.conf` via mac `terminal` (to be able to access PHPMyAdmin) but unfortunately it says

> W10: Warning: Changing a read-only file.

Comment: Your question lacks a question.

Answer (score 0):

You need admin privileges before you can open the file.  In linux it's 'sudo', not sure what it is on mac.